# Missing data into my OpenStreetMap database (with Overpass API)

Tags: openstreetmap, overpass-api

I try to use Overpass API over europe osm data.
I want to get all European country (+ their islands).
*Example, for France : Metropole + Corsica + Guadeloupe + Martinique...*

To do it, I downloaded europe OSM datafile from geofabrik : https://download.geofabrik.de/europe-latest.osm.bz2 because I saw that in Europe folder I can get all what I wanted. *Example : Europe/France/Corsica+Guadeloupe+Martinique... and same things for others countries.*

1. I followed Overpass API installation : https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API/Installation with success.
2. I tried to request on different countries with success but can't get data for many islands. 
   *Example : I can get Corsica data but CAN'T get for others French islands (Guadeloupe, Martinique...).*

Request example :

> [out:json]; node(around:50,16.24263,-61.535662); <; out geom;

--> this returned values using https://overpass-turbo.eu test tool, but nothing with my custom overpass API (*tried on different request and different GPS loc*).

Also, I checked import log files generated during import of .osm.bz2 into db/ folder, I saw many (more than hundred) lines like :

> compute_geometry: Way 83225893 used in relation 10106318 not found.

--> is it related to my problem ?

- Can the europe-latest.osm.bz2 be corrupted (missing data) ?
- Can I import islands on my current /db to not re-download all data ?

Thank a lot !

Comment: You're probably using the wrong extract. Did you notice the map in the upper right corner on https://download.geofabrik.de/europe.html ? The polygon doesn't cover all French islands.

Comment: Why did you post the same question on the OSM forum? https://forum.openstreetmap.org/viewtopic.php?id=67970

Comment: Yes, map doesnt cover in red islands, but under France (https://download.geofabrik.de/europe/france.html) I see islands. How to include islands into France if they are not in ? Concerning others forums, is it forbidden to ask same question in another forum if I don't get any response here ?